# Regular Expression Matching Odd Number of B's with A's in between (DFS to Regex)

Tags: regex, regular-language, finite-automata

Suppose I have a deterministic finite state automaton that recognizes the language L, consisting of all strings in {a, b}* which contain an odd number of b’s
such that there is at least one a between every two b’s in the string.

I managed to derive the finite state machine for this, as seen in this [example](http://automatonsimulator.com/#%7B%22type%22%3A%22DFA%22%2C%22dfa%22%3A%7B%22transitions%22%3A%7B%22start%22%3A%7B%22b%22%3A%22s0%22%2C%22a%22%3A%22start%22%7D%2C%22s0%22%3A%7B%22a%22%3A%22s1%22%2C%22b%22%3A%22s3%22%7D%2C%22s1%22%3A%7B%22b%22%3A%22s2%22%2C%22a%22%3A%22s1%22%7D%2C%22s3%22%3A%7B%22b%22%3A%22s3%22%2C%22a%22%3A%22s3%22%7D%2C%22s2%22%3A%7B%22a%22%3A%22s4%22%2C%22b%22%3A%22s3%22%7D%2C%22s4%22%3A%7B%22b%22%3A%22s0%22%2C%22a%22%3A%22s4%22%7D%7D%2C%22startState%22%3A%22start%22%2C%22acceptStates%22%3A%5B%22s0%22%2C%22s4%22%2C%22s1%22%5D%7D%2C%22states%22%3A%7B%22start%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22s0%22%3A%7B%22isAccept%22%3Atrue%2C%22top%22%3A410%2C%22left%22%3A173%7D%2C%22s1%22%3A%7B%22isAccept%22%3Atrue%2C%22top%22%3A425%2C%22left%22%3A363%7D%2C%22s3%22%3A%7B%22top%22%3A258%2C%22left%22%3A219%7D%2C%22s2%22%3A%7B%22top%22%3A428%2C%22left%22%3A547%7D%2C%22s4%22%3A%7B%22isAccept%22%3Atrue%2C%22top%22%3A572%2C%22left%22%3A335%7D%7D%2C%22transitions%22%3A%5B%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22start%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s0%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22start%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22a%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22start%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s0%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22a%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s1%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s0%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s3%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s1%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s2%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s1%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22a%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s1%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s3%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s3%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s3%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22a%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s3%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s2%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22a%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s4%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s2%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s3%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s4%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22b%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s0%22%7D%2C%7B%22stateA%22%3A%22s4%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22a%22%2C%22stateB%22%3A%22s4%22%7D%5D%2C%22bulkTests%22%3A%7B%22accept%22%3A%22babaaaababab%5Cnbaaaaaaaaaaaabaaab%5Cnbabab%5Cnb%5Cnbababaaaaa%5Cnaababab%22%2C%22reject%22%3A%22bba%5Cnbaaab%5Cnbab%5Cnbabb%5Cnbbbaa%22%7D%7D) (checkboxes mean an accepted state):

[image]

But now I'm stuck; how can I convert this into a regular expression?  I'm really struggling with this since it's a somewhat complicated example.  I tried:

```
a*b[a*ba*b]*a*
```

But this still matches strings with even numbers of b's.  What is the correct regular expression?

Comment: Forgot to ask, can there be `a`s at the start and end of the string as well? Eg `aba`, or do the `a`s have to be between `b`s?

Comment: The wording is somewhat unclear as the problem was provided to me, but I assume that a's can be at the beginning or end.  As long as it has an odd number of b's, with at least one a in between any 2 consecutive b's.

Comment: You have `a*b[a*ba*b]*a*`, you want `a*b(a*ba*b)*a*`. The square brackets indicate that you're matching all of the characters between them, i.e. it will match `a`, `b`, and `*`. Round brackets are for groups, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^a*b(?:(?:a+b){2})*a*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bSpZ40/2

In normal language:

- zero or more `a`s, followed by:
- a `b`, followed by any number of repititions of the following group:

  - (at least one `a`, followed by `b`) repeated twice (ensures total number of `b`s is odd)
- followed by zero or more `a`s

So there can be one `b`, or three `b`s, or five `b`s, etc, every `b` must have some number of `a`s between them, and there can be leading and/or trailing `a`s.